# MariaDB Maxscale throwing Access Denied though UserID/Password is Correct

Tags: mariadb, maxscale

Database Version : 10.2.14
Maxscale Version : 2.4.6

- Application is using jdbc driver to connect to database
- userid1 & userid2 is allowed to connect from anywhere i.e.
- If we connect to database directly from application server we are not receiving any issues, and connection establishes successfully, but when we connect to database via maxscale we receive intermittent Access Denied error

  Note : USERID and PASSWORD are same and NEVER CHANGE FROM DAY 1

Scenario's

```
userid1 : Connect to database via Maxscale with ID/Password throws Access Denied Error intermittently, sometimes connects successfully
Userid1 : Connect to database directly from application, works fine no issues
userid2 : Connect to database via Maxscale with ID/Password throws Access Denied Error intermittently, sometimes connects successfully
Userid2 : Connect to database directly from application, works fine no issues

Earlier Maxscale Version was 2.2.19 and we never faced issues.
From both (application & Maxscale) logs we can see only ACCESS DENIED errors for those id's.
What am unable to understand is 
1) Userid and Password never changed, so why we are receiving ACCESS DENIED when using Maxscale that too intermittently and no issue if we connect directly database.
2) IF Userid/Password passes wrongly then it should be always access denied, but in this case it's intermittently
```

Comment: missed to mentioned, the error throws is userid or password incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Similar behavior is reported as [MXS-2891](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS-2891) in the MariaDB Jira. I'd recommend reporting these problems on that Jira issue.